# Tablesorter search is not working when i applied js on table data

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, datatable, tablesorter

I am using Tablesorter search for each column on my page. I've one column name as title, on which i am using inline editing functionality i think which is interrupting the search filter because rest of the columns are simple printed and they are working fine.

```
                                          <td class="record-title">
                                        <div class="record-cont">
                                            <span data-qid="{{$question->id}}" class="label label-primary inlineques edit"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> </span>
                                            <a href="javascript://" class="lnkques">{{$question->title}}</a>
                                        </div>
                                        <span class="btn-qlike pull-right"><img src="{{asset('resources/image-path/imagename.jpg')}}" alt="like" />{{$question->likes}}</span>


                                          <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                      </td>
```

Comment: What version of tablesorter are you using? Would you please share some code and/or set up a demo of this issue.

Comment: What is this "{{$question->id}}" ? For a template engine?

Comment: Yes i am using it in laravel.

Comment: @Mottie I think its v2.28.0 . Here are the links i used

http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/js/jquery.tablesorter.js

http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/js/jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js

http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/addons/pager/jquery.tablesorter.pager.js

Thanks!

Comment: Ok, but I still don't understand the issue. Please set up a demo ([you can modify this one](https://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/wty134u7/)) to show the problem that occurs with the inline editing. Thanks!